# Can anyone identify this plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]

Can anyone please help me identify this biplane? The photo was taken in Newcastle, NSW, Australia. I can’t seem to find anything.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: No brainer, Tiger Moth or Gypsy Moth, this is not hard, overall shape strongly suggests the former.

Comment: It looks like [A17-647/VH-BGR](https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8565466), based at [Luskintyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luskintyre_Airfield). The [same aircraft](https://abpic.co.uk/pictures/view/1455030), though not easy to match :-) [History](https://aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=25694). There is a Tiger association there, flying their Tiger once a month in the vicinity.

Answer (score 5):

Looks very much like a [de Havilland DH.82 Tiger Moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Tiger_Moth).

[This webpage](http://www.adf-serials.com.au/2a17c.htm) lists all Tiger Moths used by the RAAF.